# Google Social Interaction Analytics with the Tumblr share button?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tumblr, google-analytics-api, pinterest

Does someone knows how to use Google Social Interaction Analytics with the Tumblr share button? (which is hosted on my Wordpress blog)

I've done it for Facebook and Twitter (i.e: http://visualise.ca/anne-au-cherry)

There is no information about in google's docs : http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html

P.S.: What about the Pinterest button? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tumblr Share button doesn't have any callbacks for completing the share. However, its just a link to another page. So, you can trivially add click-tracking to it:

```
$(".tumblr a").click(function(){
   _gaq.push(["_trackSocial", "Tumblr", "Click"]);
});
```

The Pinterest Pin It button is in an iframe, has no JS API, no click tracking, no "on pin" callback. So, you're lost there in terms of tracking.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Using the same Tumblr method on Pinterest is no good? It is also a link. <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://visualise.ca/alycia&media=image.jpg&description=description" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>

Comment: That JavaScript converts the link into an iframe, which is out of the scope of what you can access.